Linear surjection from Finite-dim non-Hausdorff TVS to real or complex field always continuous?
I have some confusion about whether some well-known results involving finite-dim TVS still valid if not requiring Hausdorffness in the definition of a TVS. For example,

if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{C}$ with the usual Euclidean topology and $V$ is a finite-dim $\mathbb{F}$-TVS that is not necessarily Hausdorff. Is it still true that all linear functionals $f: V\to \mathbb{F}$ are continuous?

Background. I'm trying to prove: for a general not necessarily Hausdorff TVS, a linear functional is continuous iff it has closed kernel.
For the nontrivial direction, assume $f: X\to \mathbb{F}$ has proper closed kernel $K_f\leq X$. I'm trying to prove it by decompose $f=\tilde{f}\circ \pi_f$ into quotient map $\pi_f: X\to X/K_f$ and induced functional $\tilde{f}: X/K_f\to \mathbb{F}$.
Since $\pi_f$ is automatically continuous, the question then becomes whether $\tilde{f}$ is also continuous. If the definition of a TVS doesn't require Hausdorffness, then the quotient topology makes $X/K_f$ into a TVS automatically. Closedness of $K_f$ only determines whether the topology is Hausdorff. But since the quotient space $X/K_f$ is algebraically isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}$, that is it is finite-dim. If the result that all linear functionals on finite-dim TVS are continuous is also valid without requiring Hausdorffness, then $\tilde{f}$ would also be continuous automatically. Which seems absurd. Because then all linear functionals $f$ on $X$ would be continuous automatically, regardless of what kind of kernels they have.
But I can't seem to find a negation of the result in non-Hausdorff situation online. Hence the quesiton. Hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance.
Update. For a linear functional $f: (\mathbb{F},\tau) \to (\mathbb{F}, \tau_{Eu})$, where $\tau$ is any topology that makes the field a TVS and $\tau_{Eu}$ is the usual topology, to see it is continuous iff $\tau=\tau_{Eu}$ relies on two facts.

Lemma 1. For a TVS (not necessarily Hausdorff) $X$, scalar multiplication $(c,x)\mapsto cx$ is a homeomorphism.


Lemma 2. Among all the topologies which make a vector space a TVS, the finest is the Hausdorff one.

Then, since a nonzero linear functional $f$ maps $x$ to $f(1)x$, where $f(1)\neq 0$, it is an open map from $(\mathbb{F},\tau)$ to $(\mathbb{F}, \tau_{Eu})$, but not necessarily continuous. It is cts iff $\tau$ is Hausdorff, and on finite-dim spaces, the Hausdorff topology that makes it a TVS is unique. Hence $\tau=\tau_{Eu}$.

Take $\Bbb R^2$ with seminorm $p(x,y)=\lvert x\rvert$ and the functional $f(x,y)=y$. Then $f^{-1}(0)$ is dense. Or even $f(x)=x$ on $\Bbb F^1$ with indiscrete topology (mind that by your definition $\Bbb F$ has still the Euclidean topology when it's the codomain).

@SassatelliGiulio ah it's so trivial... thanks!!

@SassatelliGiulio yes, for the linear functional, the codomain field still has the usual topology, only the quotient space might have a different one
